# p:selectCheckboxMenu very slow

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am totally new to JSF, and I can't get it way one simple selectCheckboxMenu element takes a lot of time to show over 15000 elemente when I click on it:

Code:

```
        <p:column style="width:30%;">
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="lossesReportReportTripIdSelectId"
                filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:100%;"
                value="#{reportsBean.filters.selectedTripIds}"
                label="#{message['labels.tripId']}" onHide="tripIdSelectRC()" converter="javax.faces.Long">
                <f:selectItems id="lossesReportReportTripIdSelectItemsId"
                    value="#{reportsBean.filters.tripIds}" var="tripId"
                    itemLabel="#{tripId}" itemValue="#{tripId}" />
                <p:remoteCommand name="tripIdSelectRC" partialSubmit="true" />
            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
        </p:column>
```

And variabile filters is a simple class (not inheriting anything) that contains all the fields that I require to populate the client site page....

reportsBean - is a ManagedBean with ViewScoped.

Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Do you really want to show a list with 15000 elements??

Comment: Unfortunately yes, i have to show all those ids.

Comment: first of all it is a PrimeFaces component, not JSF, so your tagging and title is wrong. Secondly, Showing all 15000 is a wrong requirement, use an multi select autocomplete for this. If you really need the 15000, either try a different browser or use a `h:selectCheckboxMenu` if there is one, but you'll loose the filtering.